# Building Web Based SQL like client

Tags: java, user-interface, web-applications

We are storing our data in an internal key-value store in few different data formats, To view or update data in the store I have built a command line tool which accepts a commands in a custom query language (similar to Object Query Language) parses, interprets and displays it on the console.

I am thinking of building a web based GUI for this. Since I have limited experience with this, wanted to know what would be the easiest way to do it (in java).

Currently the UI just needs to have two elements a text area for accepting commands and a table for displaying the output. The output table should be simple enough to implement but I am stuck on the input element part, since the console application provides history of the commands by default but I am not sure what GUI element would be good for this. An alternative would be to have a big text box in which the user can type multiple commands and run any of them by simply highlighting and executing it like most standard gui sql clients do (
http://mywebsql.net/screenshots/?cat=Sql+Editors#/images/screens/02.Sql%20Editors/Multiple%20Editors.png)

I went through the Google Web Tool kit widget gallery ( https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefWidgetGallery ) but none of them seem to fit my need.

Any suggestions on this would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the answer? Or what was your solution?

Comment: I haven't, we are still using a console based app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll find any component providing a history of previously executed commands for you. But nobody forbids you to implement your own solution.

Just provide a text field or text area to type a command, and display a list of previous commands next to the text field/area. When a previous command is clicked, replace the text of the text area by the text of the clicked command. And when a command is executed, add it to the history list.

Any web framework, from basic servlet/JSP to component-based framewoks, should allow you doing that.